# entity framework core reuse a set of include statements

Tags: ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

How can I clean up my entity 'includes' to reuse the same set of statements? I'm trying to reuse a set of Includes while staying DRY.

Before

```
_context.Accounts
              .Include(x=> x.Status)
              .Include(x=> x.Type)
              .Include(x=> x.Phones)
              .Include(x=> x.Users)
              .Include(x=> x.Admins)
```

After:

```
_context.Accounts.CustomIncludes()
```

Comment: Put the includes in a custom extension method?

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
public static class DataExtensions
{
    public static Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable<Account, List<Admin>> CustomIncludes(this DbSet<Account> accounts)
    {
        return accounts
            .Include(p => p.Status)
            .Include(p => p.Type)
            .Include(p => p.Phones)
            .Include(p => p.Users)
            .Include(p => p.Admins);
    }
}
```

Then you can say

```cs
context.Accounts.CustomIncludes();
```

Comment: Does not seem like reusing the include statements to me. It seems to me that it is put in an extension method but still starts from `DbSet<Account>`. If it would start from `IQueryable<Account>` that would seem like a possible reuse to me. Or is there another, different, `DbSet<Account>` on which that extension method could be applied?

Comment: ef core does not make it easy to reuse a set of includes given a dynamic starting point. IN order to get around that in my project, I created a thin wrapper to allow reusing includes regardless of the starting point. https://github.com/jasekiw/resuable-ef-core-includes